# Jquery alterar um valor de um html salvo em variável

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Estou utilizando o tinyMCE pra editar alguns campos e para isso eu mantenho um HTML salvo em uma variável na inicialização da página

```
let edtInputText = `
  <div class="custom-panel">
   <label>Define um nome do campo <input id="iname" type="text" name="iname" value=""></label>
   <label>Exemplo <input id="iexemp" type="text" name="iexemp"></label>
  </div> `;
```

Porém em dado momento eu queria preencher os values, via `jQuery` tentei utilizando o find e atacando uma cópia direta da variável `edtInputText`.

```
let inputElm = edtInputText;

//$(inputElm).find("#iname").attr("value", "abc123"); //Uma tentativa
//$(inputElm).find("#iname").first().val("abc123"); //Outra tentativa
$(inputElm).find("#iname").val("abc123");
console.log(inputElm);
```

Mas de forma alguma parece que consigo alterar o valor. Sempre que faço um `console.log()` da variável `inputElm` ele continua com o html original. Tentei rodar o `parseHTML()` também, ainda assim sem sucesso.

Obs. Estou tentando com esse método pois se eu usar o `$(inputElm).find("#iname").val()` eu consigo ver o valor, então estou supondo que também seja possível alterar o valor, mesmo sem fazer um parse.

Tem alguma forma melhor de atacar esses values?

Deixo aqui um exemplo do funcionamento. Sei que após inserir no html consigo manipular, mas devido a uma limitação do tinyMCE preciso preparar esse trecho antes de inserir nele.

```js
  let edtInputText = `
      <div class="custom-panel">
       <label>Define um nome do campo <input id="iname" type="text" name="iname" value=""></label>
      </div> `;

    let inputElm = edtInputText;
    
    
    //$(inputElm).find("#iname").attr("value", "abc123"); //Uma tentativa
    //$(inputElm).find("#iname").first().val("abc123"); //Outra tentativa
    $(inputElm).find("#iname").val("abc123");
    console.log(inputElm);
    

    $("#teste").html(inputElm)
```

```css
label {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste">
</div>
```

Comment: "Sei que após inserir no html consigo manipular, mas devido a uma limitação do tinyMCE preciso preparar esse trecho antes de inserir nele.". Então por que não coloca em uma div oculta, trata, depois pega o conteúdo tratado e usa no tinyMCE?

Comment: Pensei nisso agora a pouco. É que estou montando uma espécie de componente e queria manter o html da página mais limpo possível, mas como último recurso acredito que atenda bem.

Comment: `$(inputElm).find("#iname").val()` se o elemento tem um ID, que deve ser único, basta fazer `$("#iname").val("novo valor")`

Comment: A variável `inputElm` é uma  string  que representa um texto e não um objeto que representa o **html**. `.val()` é usado em objetos do tipo **DOM** para resolver tem que parsear a string  para dom. `let inputElm = $.parseHTML(edtInputText);`

Comment: @RicardoPontual tentei assim, mas veja que o `$("#iname")` não está dentro do dom e sim numa string de uma variável.

Comment: @stack.cardoso correto. Porém é possível pesquisar dentro dele diretamente mesmo antes de fazer o parse. Com o parse também tentei mas não consegui alterar o valor. No final to seguindo com o caminho apontado pelo amigo, de deixar num elemento oculto e tratar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seguindo a ideia do membro @Benilson coloquei uma div oculta carregando o html, onde faço toda a manipulação e depois pego html pronto.

```
$("#replacements").html(edtInputText);
$("#replacements").find("#iname").attr("value", $(ob).attr("name"));
$("#replacements").find("#imin").attr("value", $(ob).attr("minlength"));
$("#replacements").find("#imax").attr("value", $(ob).attr("maxlength"));
$("#replacements").find("#ititle").attr("value", $(ob).attr("placeholder"));
$("#replacements").find("#itype").attr("value", $(ob).data().field);
```

E na hora de preencher o tinyMCE eu pego o html pronto

```
edtOpt = {
      title: 'Adicionar campo do Tipo Texto',
      level: 'info',
      body: {
        type: 'panel',
        name: 'text_field',
        items: [
          {
            type: 'htmlpanel', // an HTML panel component
            html: $("#replacements").html()
          },
        ]
      },
    ...
```